# Searching by query for attributes of complex objects in Java EE

Tags: jpa, jakarta-ee

I have created the object **Person**, I can deleted and modify it and I can also search for **Person** by his name or phonenumber... but I don't know for exemple how to search for a person by his ** home address**. Here is my code:

My entity **Person.java**:

```
public class Person{
private Long id;
private String name;
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Address address;
....
}
```

My entity **Address.java**

```
public class Address{
...
private String streetName;
...
}
```

And here is the most interesting function that I am trying to modify to get what I want, I would like to search for **Persons** who live in xxx (streetName = xxx). Here is my function **getByQuery**:

```
public List<Person> getByQuery(PersonSearchQuery searchQuery) {
    Map<String, String> criteriaQuery = new HashMap<String, String>();
    if (searchQuery.getName() != null)
        criteriaQuery.put("name",searchQuery.getName());
    TypedQuery<Person> query =  this.findByQuery(criteriaQuery);
    return query.getResultList();
}
```

The object **PersonSearchQuery** contains just to attributes name (String) and streetName (String) and their getters.

Function **findByQuery**:

```
public TypedQuery<T> findByQuery(Map<String, String> criteriaQuery) {
    CriteriaBuilder builder = this.em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<T> criteria = builder.createQuery(this.entityClass);

    Root<T> root = criteria.from(this.entityClass);
    criteria.select(root);

    Predicate predicate = builder.conjunction();
    if (criteriaQuery.size() != 0) {
        for (String key : criteriaQuery.keySet()) {
            try{
            predicate = builder.and(predicate, builder.equal(root.<String>get(key), criteriaQuery.get(key)));
            }catch(IllegalArgumentException e){
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
    criteria.where(predicate);
    return this.em.createQuery(criteria);
}
```

So I can search for **Persons** by their names by I cannot search for them by **streetName** the problem is my function **getByQuery** I would like to do something like this:

```
if (searchQuery.getStreetName() != null)
        criteriaQuery.put("Address.streetName",searchQuery.getStreetName());
```

The problem is I don't know how to define the key in this case. Thanks for your help

Comment: you JOIN from "root" to Address. You then can get fields of the Address object.

Comment: So you propose to me to change the function **findByQuery**? But the problem is that I would like to use this function a lot of times (factorization),

Comment: Anyway how can I use my JOIN @NeilStockton

Comment: If you need to access fields of a non-candidate object then you need to JOIN. You use JOINs by consulting a basic JPA Criteria documentation, such as http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_5_1/jpa/query.html#_criteria_api_from_clause_joins

Comment: Thanks @NeilStockton, now it is working I just want to generalize all cases by using one function and not to have to create a function for address and for every complex object.

Answer (score 0):

I only use `CriteriaBuilder` if I have several similar Entities which needs to be used/rendered in the same way, so if person is the only Entity with an Address reference I would just use JPQL, like this:

```
entityManager.createQuery(
  "select p from Person p where p.address.streetName like :streetName", Person.class)
  .setParameter("streetName", "xyz" + "%").getResultList()
```

The main reason I tend to avoid CriteriaBuilder, is because it has a rather steep learning curve, and you need to write a lot of code to express very simple concepts. In contrast any developer familiar with SQL can read and maintain JPQL code.

These days I always use frameworks, like DeltaSpike Data (for EE) and Spring Data, they both implements most of the basic DAO/Repository features, so If you don't mind an extra dependency (and some magic) it can save you a lot of boilerplate JPA code.

Comment: I am using many Entities @Klaus, that's why I am using CriteriaBuilder. Otherwise, I have resolved my problem but by creating a function containg lot of lignes to verify every complex objects (join).